# how to change date format in Android?

Tags: android

I am receiving date and time in the format of 13/10/26 20:02.
I like to change that format to the new format as "EEE,d MMM yyyy,HH:mm:ss".
What could be the best way to do that?

EDIT1:

Now I tried as follow

```
String date = "26/10/2013 20:55"; 
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,d MMM yyyy,HH:mm:ss"); 
String newdateformat = df.format(Date.parse(date));
```

But now newdateformat is "Tue,10 Feb 2015,20:55:00"; Why the date is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426492/change-date-string-format-in-android

Comment: Thanks I have figured out. It should be String date = "10/26/2013 20:55";

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy  hh:mm a");
String date = sdf.format(Date.parse("Your date"));
```

Answer (score 0):

to change the format of the date in android, try this code

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

    Date date=new Date();
    String newDate =formatter.format(date.getTime()); 

    Toast.makeText(this,newDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date(your date);
    String date_format = sdf.format(date);
```

hope this will help