# How to format string to date in Android

Tags: android

In my application I one string such as 2023-2-14 and I want convert this to 2023-02-14.
I write below codes:

```
val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
val date: Date = format.parse(startDateStr)
Log.e("dateLog",""+date)
```

But in logcat show me this : `Wed Feb 15 00:00:00 GMT+03:30 2023`

Why? I used this format : **yyyy-MM-d**d. 
Why not used this format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are just parsing date, without a time, thus `date` object have set 00 for hour, day etc. now use [`format`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/DateFormat#format(java.util.Date)) method for converting old `String` to new one

```
val formatAs = "yyyy-MM-dd"
var format = SimpleDateFormat(formatAs)
val date: Date = format.parse(startDateStr)
Log.e("dateLog","date:"+date)
String dateAsStringFormatted = format.format(date);
Log.e("dateLog","dateAsStringFormatted:"+dateAsStringFormatted)
```

some other answers in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426492/change-date-string-format-in-android)